# Problem on export npm package method name

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I wrote an npm package for React that have several method and components exported publicly.
Every thing works good in using, but the problem is when I want to import this npm package methods to my app, my code editor can not detect method ( it has not problem for any other npm packages ), I think there is a problem in webpack config

```js
// webpack.config.js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        'react': 'commonjs react'
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: No any error, When the app build and run it works correctly, my problem is where my code editor don't suggest any of my npm package exported method